# Can't read image from SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I try to read images from my SQL Server database I get an error: on the following line:

```
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

My code:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}

private ArrayList GetImagesFromDB(string code)
{
    ArrayList images = new ArrayList();

    SqlCommand selectImagesCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM images WHERE code = '"+code+"'");
    selectImagesCommand.Connection = myConnection;

    if(myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed){      
        myConnection.Open();
    }

    SqlDataReader imagesReader = selectImagesCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (imagesReader.Read())
    {
        byte[] newimagebytesRecord = (byte[])imagesReader["image"];
        images.Add(byteArrayToImage(newimagebytesRecord));
    }

    return images;
}
```

Comment: please post all your flow... we need more code to help you

Comment: updated the code snippet

Comment: in what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

Answer (score 0):

Use [SqlDataReader.GetStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method.

So you would do something along the lines:

```
using(SqlDataReader imageReader = selectSingleImageCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
    if (imageReader.Read())
    {
        using (Stream backendStream = imageReader.GetStream(0))
        {
            //Do whater you need with the Stream
        }
    }   
}
```

You migh also be able to iterate over the reader (selecting multiple images) and open stream by stream - I haven't use it that way though, so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
  try
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSelect=new SqlCommand("select Picture" + 
              " from tblImgData where ID=@ID",this.sqlConnection1);
        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int,4);
        cmdSelect.Parameters["@ID"].Value=this.editID.Text;

        this.sqlConnection1.Open();
        byte[] barrImg=(byte[])cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();
        string strfn=Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
        FileStream fs=new FileStream(strfn, 
                          FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        fs.Write(barrImg,0,barrImg.Length);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        pictureBox1.Image=Image.FromFile(strfn);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
```